# Kendo Dropdownlist mobile rendering

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dropdown

Is it possible to render the dropdownlist as a select on mobiles.
So that it works as a native select html tag on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Kendo UI DropDownList is rendered similar to an ActionSheet when used in Kendo UI Mobile exactly with this idea in mind. Check the [Forms demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/m/index.html#/mobile/m/forms/index.html) in a mobile device.

Comment: How can i force this behavior on a website that is also used by desktop ?

Comment: You mean to look the same on mobile and desktop, or native-like only on mobile and not on desktop?

Comment: Native look only on mobile.